# How to add data to relative table Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have model `Object` and model `Prototype`.

Incoming data`($_POST)` is array `prototype_id[]`:

```
prototype_id[] = 1;
prototype_id[] = 2;
prototype_id[] = 3;
```

That should be saved in table `ObjectPrototypes`. No i dont have this model.

So, in controller I do:

```
 $object = new Object();
 $object->name = "Object";
```

How to add/attach prototype_id[] to saved object `$object`?

**Important:**

Object can has one or more prototypes

Comment: If you don't have an ObjectPrototypes model, there's nothing Laravel can do for you. You'll have to insert them yourself into the DB the 'oldschool' way.

Comment: As I know to have ObjectPrototypes is not requires, because Laravel does third table if to set correct reations many-to-many. Can you help with this?

Comment: Actually you're right. A model might not be necessary if you only want to update the pivot-table of a many-to-many relationship. You could define the rationship on the Object-model explicitly like `function prototypes() { return $this->belongsToMany('Dummy\Class', 'object_prototype_pivot_table_name', 'object_id', 'prototype_id'); }` and then try `$object->prototypes()->sync($request->input('prototype_id'))` (after saving the `$object`, of course). It might work if Laravel doesn't need to actually resolve the other model for some reason.

Comment: And as @rap-2-h already pointed out, have a look at the docs for some more insight on how Laravel handles many-to-many relationships and what you can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

One (quick) solution could be to do raw insert on this table. Assuming pivot table name is `object_prototype`, here is what you could do:

```
$object = new Object();
$object->name = "Object";
$object->save();

foreach($request->input('prototype_id') as $p) {
    \DB::table('object_prototype')->insert([
        'object_id' => $object->id, 
        'prototype_id' => $prototype
    ]);
}
```

It should work, thought it's not really Laravelish.

You may also work with pivot, but it requires more boilerplate. You may have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships and here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse That's what I do usually but it's a bit too long for a short answer and I think Laravel Doc is more complete.